# What are Fletcher-Reeves and the Wolfe inexact line search?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, maxima-minima, gradient-descent

I need to implement the Fletcher-Reeves conjugate gradient method with the Wolfe inexact line search to find the stationary point of

$$S(y) =20 \sum_{i=1}^9 ( 1 + y_{i+1} - y^2_{i} - y_i)^2$$

While googling Fletcher-Reeves method, I found the following iterative algorithm on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method).
[image]
My concern is that I don't really understand, what the Wolfe inexact line search is.
Also, I cannot get what $A$ and $b$ are for my function.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: The algorithm you've shown is an algorithm for solving $Ax=b$, the fletcher-reeves algorithm is for minimizing $\|Ax-b\|^2$, a slightly different problem. I don't see how to find an $A$ to match your problem when you have a $y_i^2$ term.

Comment: You have to use nonlinear CG method. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_conjugate_gradient_method .. and instead of computing an exact linesearch one uses Wolfe.

Comment: There are nine equations with ten unknowns. I don't think any (nonlinear) CG method will work.

Comment: Or is the $i \rightarrow (i+1)$ indexing meant as circular, i.e. $9 \rightarrow 1$ ?

Comment: @HandeBruijn, I don't think it's circular. $y_1$ and $y_9$ can be different.

Comment: No, question is whether $y_1$ and $y_{10}$ are different.

Comment: Suppose that we have $\,S(y_1,y_2) = (1+y_2-y_1^2-y_1)^2+(1+y_1-y_2^2-y_2)^2\,$ [circular]. Then solve the equations
$\partial S/\partial y_1 = \partial S/\partial y_2  = 0$. This already results in three real-valued and two complex solutions:
$$
S(0,0)=2 \quad ; \quad S(1,1)=S(-1,-1)=0 \quad ; \quad S(-1/4+i\sqrt{3}/4,-1/4-i\sqrt{3}/4)=S(-1/4-i\sqrt{3}/4,-1/4+i\sqrt{3}/4)=27/16
$$
No doubt that the case $\sum_{i=1}^9$ is even more prohibitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, you can find a working Wolfe line search in the [scipy source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.6.3/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py#L193-L335). There is also a BFGS algorithm if you want.